# jQuery TableSorter not sorting correctly and I don't know how

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I have seven columns and I would like to have them sort correctly,

The first column has numbers but it doesn't order them the way I would like them to be ordered:

```
Example:
5016
502
5020
5023
```

where I would like it to sort like this:

```
Example:
502
5016
5020
5023
```

Now the 2nd column has a combination of numbers and letters
example is like above but has a letter in the front before each number
I would like to sort that by numbers, then by letters

```
Example:
441
B441
821
822
823
C823
```

or even like this would be OK

```
Example:
441
821
822
823
B441
C823
```

and finally,
the 3rd column is more complex it has a image before the words example is:
 Billy Jones
 Anna Walters
 Bob Smith
 Tom Henderson

All I want it to order by (names) letters...

```
Example:
<img src="img_tr122.png">&nbsp;Anna Walters
<img src="img_tr122.png">&nbsp;Billy Jones
<img src="img_tr122.png">&nbsp;Bob Smith
<img src="img_tr122.png">&nbsp;Tom Henderson
```

here is what I have in the JavaScript so far but I don't know how to get everything to work..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
$.tablesorter.defaults.widgets = ['zebra']; 
    $("table").tablesorter({ 
        // pass the headers argument and assing a object 
        headers: { 
            // assign the third column (we start counting zero) 
            2: { 
                // disable sort because I don't know how to sort it correctly.
                sorter: false 
            },
            6: { 
                // disable sort for this (last) column because it is a menu only.
                sorter: false 
            } 
        } 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

PLEASE HELP....

THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original tablesorter (v2.0.5) doesn't do alphanumeric sorting. But you can use my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) to sort your data using this code:

```
$('table').tablesorter({

    // Add a theme
    theme : 'blue',

    // extract text from the table
    textExtraction: {
        2: function(node) {
            // move swap first and last name
            return $.trim($(node).text() || '').replace(/(\w+)\s(\w+)/g,'$2 $1');
        }
    },

    // include zebra and any other widgets:
    widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']

});
```

I wasn't sure how you wanted to sort the last column. The `textExtraction` option contains code to sort the last column by last name first. If you want to sort by the first name, then just remove the entire option.

Here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/53/) of that code in action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://tablesorter.openwerk.de/ which has the functionality you need and it has locale support, UI themes support, support for german date format and decimal points.